# How to fill boolean set-Method with int value

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a set-Method setSelected() which expect a boolean. SQLite is not able to store boolean values, so I decided to make it as integer, and convert the boolean to int:

```
values.put(COLUMN_SELECTED, (member.isSelected()) ? 1 : 0 );
```

This worked already for me. But now I want to set the value again, but how I can pass the int to the method which requires a boolean:

```
member.setSelected(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SELECTED));
```

ERROR-> setSelection(Boolean) in Member cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: @KevinEsche `overloading` ?? Why here ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ it´s not necesarry, but you wont have to rewrite the same comparison if you would use it at multiple places in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`ContentValues` supports boolean values, and automatically converts to `0`/`1` when writing to the database.

To convert a number into a boolean value, just compare it against zero:

```java
car.setSelected(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SELECTED) != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do, `car.setSelected(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SELECTED) == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
car.setSelected(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SELECTED)==1 ? true : false );
```

Use the same conditional operator on int

or simply

```
car.setSelected(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SELECTED)==1 ); // true or false
```